# Problems with the variable position, C#

Tags: c#

What's wrong with the code?
Why on the second report shows a mistake?

```
string level;
int key;

command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = 'admin'";

connection.Open();
Reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (Reader.Read())
{
    level = Convert.ToString(Reader["level"]);
    key = Convert.ToInt32(Reader["key"]);

    MessageBox.Show(level); //Work fine
}

MessageBox.Show(level); //Show error:  Use of unassigned local variable 'level'
```

Comment: does this error show up only if there are no rows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler has no way of knowing level got a value. For all it knows, `Reader.Read()` always returns false, thus leaving level without a value.

The most common solution to this is to just initialize level to `null` (or I agree with AdaTheDev, `string.Empty` might be a good choice here too)

Answer (score 4):

If the query returns no results, level would never have been assigned a value.

You can initialise the variable when you declare it to prevent it:

```
string level = String.Empty;
```

Comment: This works, but I'd recommend Matt Greer's solution instead, as null is how you express a lack of a value.

Answer (score 1):

set level to a default value when initialising the variable

```
string level = string.Empty;
```

The compiler knows that the variable may not be assigned to inside the while loop as this may not be executed on all code paths.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that Reader.Read() will return false immediately, in which case "level" will never be assigned to.  If you initialise the variable with `string level = string.Empty;` you'll get around it.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good practice to initialize your variables. C# enforces it showing that message. No one can guaranty that your level variable will be assigned inside the while - as @AdaTheDev pointed out